# How to create a persistent database throughout Gitlab pipeline life cycle?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab

I've got a ticket to create a postgres database in one stage of a gitlab pipeline but that database needs to be used in later stages as well. My understanding is that a gitlab pipeline shuts down one stage before proceeding to the next so is there a solution to create a persistent database in a gitlab stage inside a docker container to be used between stages?

Answer (score 2):

The Parent-Child pipelines may help. Check this link for details: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/